# Hibernate : How to do association mapping for composite key in HBM file

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

**Question**:There are two tables named **specialday** and **rule**.In rule table one column named specialrule refer to specialday table and want to make rule.hbm.xml file in a way so that when i fetch rule object from table it will also fetch associated specialday object.
here i have write down **specialdaydata.hbm.xml** and **rule.hbm.xml**

- SpecialDayData.hbm.xml

```
    <composite-id name="specialDayIdData" class="SpecialDayIdData">
      <key-property name="name" column="NAME" type="string"/>
      <key-property name="specialRule" column="SPECIAL_RULE" type="string"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="type" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="TYPE" sql-type="NUMERIC" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    ---other column
    ------
</class>
```

- Rule.hbm.xml

```
    <id name="rule" column="RULESTRING" type="string">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>


    <property name="specialRule" type="string">
        <column name="SPECIAL_RULE" sql-type="VARCHAR(64)" not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <!--specialRule Refer SpecialDayData   -->
    <many-to-one >
         Stuck over here
    </many-to-one>


</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<many-to-one
        name="specialRule"
        column="SPECIAL_RULE"
        class="ClassName"
        not-null="true" lazy="true"


    >
```

Make lazy="true" in Rule.hbm.xml file

Comment: Special Day has composite key containing name and specialRule then how it will decide to fetch associated SpecialDayData object from table?